# Cant get the google drive js file upload example working

Tags: google-drive-api

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js

I follow (c/p) the example, everything works well (auth etc) until i get to the point of submitting a file. the only response i get from drive is 400: Bad Request - Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.

here are my request headers:

Host    www.googleapis.com

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Connection  keep-alive

Content-Type    multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8; boundary="-------314159265350000023846"

Authorization   Bearer ya29.AHES6ZSUZuBpl00000kTgoNfAsfgiffGPKl-TsIeoT0b00000qcoiWE

X-ClientDetails appVersion=5.0%20(X11)&platform=Linux%20x86_64&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(X11%3B%20Linux%20x86_64
%3B%20rv%3A12.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F12.0

X-JavaScript-User-Agent google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta

X-Origin    http://xxx.com

X-Referer   http://xxx.com

X-Goog-Encode-Response-If...    base64

Referer features_%2Fam%3DQQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItR000000MKD-NmdZUrhxHhwd0000eNMw">https://www.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.Y3In_W4Itv8.O%2Fm%3D_*features*_%2Fam%3DQQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItR000000MKD-NmdZUrhxHhwd0000eNMw

Content-Length  848332

Pragma  no-cache

Cache-Control   no-cache

ideas?
Could it be a unicode thing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yay turns out the uploaded html code got corrupted because of a char set issue. works now.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm having the same issue.